Select routing policy based on gateway address
I run a wireguard interface wg0 on my remote VPS, the wireguard interface has 2 IP addresses, 10.9.0.1 & 10.9.0.2, the network interface of the VPS is ens3 (1.2.3.4), and I also run a VPN connection on the VPS wg-vpn (172.16.0.2)
I've written 2 route tables on my local router.
10.9.0.0/24 dev wireguard
default via 10.9.0.1 dev wireguard
(other condition)
10.9.0.0/24 dev wireguard
default via 10.9.0.2 dev wireguard
I'd like all the network traffic through gateway 10.9.0.1 go through wg-vpn, and the traffic through gateway 10.9.0.2 go to ens3 directly.
How to do that?

In short, you cannot.
Keep in mind that the gateway address does not go into the IP header. It only affects lower-layer addressing, e.g. physical interface selection or Ethernet header, while the IP packets only ever indicate the "real" destination.
So the first problem that WireGuard tunnels are "L3 only" – they don't carry any kind of lower-layer addressing (such as MAC addressing) that would allow the receiver to distinguish between those two cases – and with such a tunnel, both routes result in exactly the same packet being delivered to the VPS. (In other words, both routes work exactly as if they were just dev wireguard with no gateway at all.)
If you want to use WireGuard, the only way to distinguish between such routes is to set up two independent tunnels so that you'd have separate wg0 and wg1 interfaces on both ends (i.e. not two peers on the same tunnel), then use ip rule on the VPS to associate each interface with its own routing table.
But even with "L2" tunnels that carry Ethernet frames (complete with MAC addresses), such as VXLAN or EoIP, it would still be difficult to detect which gateway address was used by the client, because the VPS tunnel interface would still have a single MAC address for both its IP addresses. It would be possible, but you'd additionally need something like a "macvlan" interface on top of the tunnel (to provide a second MAC address)… and then you have two interfaces anyway.
(Which would be fine – two distinct tunnel interfaces would still be the easiest approach regardless of tunnel type, as it allows you to use various existing mechanisms such as ip rule or ip vrf on Linux, without needing weird trickery like nftables packet mark assignment by MAC address – but it would still be more complex than copy-pasting the WireGuard tunnel.)

There is a different approach that could be used: routing by ToS/DSCP marks, which are also part of the IP header and indeed were even planned to be used as routing criteria once upon a time (Linux still supports that, though you probably won't not need it exactly).
If you can get software to consistently set some known IP ToS/DSCP value (or perhaps force it via nftables on the client), you could match that in nftables or iptables rules on the VPS and assign different packet marks, then use ip rule to select routing tables based on the mark.
